# Adding Experience points to a database php

Tags: php, mysql, database

I have been working on a game for my computing coursework and I'm coming across an issue with php.

When my game sends the information containing the amount of experience earned, the end result of the number in the data base is random, for example if the xp earned is 300 the xp put into the database is 900. If the xp is 100 it's 400 and it continues an a random pattern like that. This is the php code:

```
<?php

$host = "host";
$user = "user";
$pass = "pass";
$database = "database";

$username = $_POST['username'];
$exp = $_POST['exp'];

$db = mysqli_connect($host,$user,$pass,$database) or die ('ERROR: Could not connect to database!');
mysqli_select_db($db, $database) or die ("ERROR: Could not connect to database!");


{
$ins = mysqli_query($db, "UPDATE UserInfo SET xp=xp+" . $exp . " WHERE username = '".$username."';");
if ($ins)
{
echo "Succesfully Updated!";
}
else
{
die ("Error!" . mysql_error());
}
}


?>
```

Any help would be very useful.

Comment: $ins = mysqli_query($db, "UPDATE UserInfo SET xp = xp + $exp  WHERE username = '".$username."';");

Comment: try to displaying $exp to see what value your code is receiving

Answer (score 0):

I see now: remove" if ($ins) statement" because query is executed every time when that "if" is executed

Comment: if you need only currently earned xp write: SET xp=" . $exp

Comment: but it's still random, for example if you are a new player (so the old xp will be 0) and you earn 200 xp the value put into the database will be like 1000 instead of 200 so it hasn't been added.

Comment: try echouing out $exp when    if (true) and tell me if it's the random one or the expected one

Comment: after adding a line to echo $exp it says "200 Succesfully Updated!" (the successfully updated part coming from the final echo) 200 was the xp... but in the database it says 600 (apparently 0 + 200 = 600)

Comment: Hmm, I get what you mean about the if statement. Unfortunately removing it did not seem to change anything, it's still the same issue. :/